# Como verificar se algum texto foi selecionado antes de copiá-lo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo uma tabela com diversas informações, em servidor local. Uso um jQuery para detectar quando clico em uma linha e passar essas informações via GET. Na mesma página, eu trato essas informações com PHP isset().

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET["contrato"])){
    if($_GET["contrato"]!=""){
        $contrato = $_GET["contrato"];
        $nome = $_GET["nome"];
        $tel = $_GET["tel"];
        # Trabalho com as variáveis  
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum contato selecionado!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nenhum contato selecionado!";
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr[class=contato]").click(function(){
        document.execCommand("copy"); //copia o que estiver selecionado
        var msg = "?contrato="+$(this).children(".g0").html()+
                  "&nome="$(this).children(".g1").html()+
                  "&tel="$(this).children(".g2").html();
        window.location.href = msg;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class="contato">
        <td class="g0">1000</td>
        <td class="g1">João</td>
        <td class="g2">DDD+numero</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="contato">
        <td class="g0">1001</td>
        <td class="g1">Maria</td>
        <td class="g2">DDD+numero</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="contato">
        <td class="g0">1002</td>
        <td class="g1">José</td>
        <td class="g2">DDD+numero</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Da forma que está, sempre que clicar em uma linha da tabela, o comando `document.execCommand("copy");` vai ser executado, mesmo se não houver nada selecionado.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de verificar, em javascript/jQuery, se o usuário selecionou algo antes de executar o comando para copiar.

Comment: $().select() só funciona com input ou textarea veja https://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: Então não existe uma forma de verificar se algum texto foi selecionado?

Comment: @PauloDosSantos não fui eu que dei o downvote, mas acho que é melhor você explicar o que você quer fazer. Digo isso porque pode ser um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/6333) e pode ter uma maneira melhor de fazer o que você quer.

Comment: @fernandosavio Entendo! Mas o 8biT entendeu exatamente o que eu queria dizer. Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com os eventos **onmouseup** e **onkeyup** você poderia criar uma função para verificar se algo foi selecionado ou não.

Feito isto você poderá seguir com a sua necessidade (copiar, alterar estilo, ocultar ...)

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function algumTextoSelecionado() {
  var texto = "";
  
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined")
   texto = window.getSelection().toString();
  else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text")
   texto = document.selection.createRange().text;
  
  if (texto.trim())
   alert("Texto selecionado: " + texto);
 }
 
 document.onmouseup = algumTextoSelecionado;
 document.onkeyup = algumTextoSelecionado;
```

```html
<html>
 <body> 
    <div>
        <h2>Algum titulo<h2>
        <p>Texto1.1 texto1.2 texto1.3.</p>
        <p>Texto2.1 texto2.2 texto2.3.</p>
        <p>Texto3.1 texto3.2 texto3.3.</p>
    </div>
  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="master.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Só não entendi porque recebi tantos downvotes.  :(

Comment: @PauloDosSantos sua pergunta parece simples. - " Ok, você quer verificar se algo foi selecionado" mas por quê ? Podemos ajudar melhor se especificar exatamente o que precisa pois provavelmente poderíamos encontrar mais de uma maneira de encontrar a solução para o seu problema. Não negativei sua pergunta mas talvez seja por isso. Fico grato em ajudar!

Comment: Sim, por isso mesmo eu tirei o "algo" e coloquei "texto". Mas não é texto de textarea ou input do tipo text. Não sei como explicar melhor: só queria que quando eu selecionasse alguma palavra, ela fosse para o clipboard, sem dar Ctrl+C. Só isso. O que eu não sabia era como fazer essa verificação que você fez. Muito obrigado, mais uma vez.

Answer (score 5):

Opa, blza!?
Para pegar o texto selecionado é relativamente simples. Segue o exemplo:

```js
function isTextSelected(input){
   var startPos = input.selectionStart;
   var endPos = input.selectionEnd;
   var doc = document.selection;

   if(doc && doc.createRange().text.length != 0){
      return true;
   }else if (!doc && input.value.substring(startPos,endPos).length != 0){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

$('input').click(function(){
   
   if(isTextSelected($('#textareaId')[0])){
      alert(getSelectionText());
   } 
});

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textareaId">
    teste
    teste
    teste
    teste
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Test" />
```

No lugar do alert, prossiga com as ações que necessita.
Abraços!

Comment: Obrigado por responder à minha pergunta! Mas minha ideia seria não usar textareas ou inputs, muito mesmo um botão. :/